# ViaMichelin API unable to request route planner

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, guzzle

I found absolutely anything about issue with this api on google but this api is a client choice.

I want to use the route planner api provided by ViaMichelin.

[here is the doc for the endpoint](https://api.viamichelin.com/documentation/api-rest/services/route-planner/)

I'm using guzzle to make the call from my app. Each time I'm calling this endpoint it keeps telling me that `lg` params is required.
Here is my guzzle debug dump

```
*   Trying 212.11.63.81...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to apir.viamichelin.com (212.11.63.81) port 80 (#0)
> GET /apir/1/route.json?lg=fra&steps=1%3Ae%3A7.77272%3A48.56716%3B1%3Ae%3A7.4978113%3A48.3%3B&country=fra&veht=0&authkey=MY_KEY&callback=json_decode&charset=utf8 HTTP/1.1
Host: apir.viamichelin.com
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.62.0 PHP/7.2.12
Content-Type: application/json

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Cache-Control: private
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: application/x-javascript;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Date: Thu, 21 Feb 2019 08:55:16 GMT
< X-Cnection: close
<
* Connection #0 to host apir.viamichelin.com left intact
{#1308
  +"error": {#1310
    +"errorCode": 4
    +"errorMsg": "Invalid request parameter value : "lg" is required"
  }
}
```

As you can see, `lg` is the very first param on the url. I also tried to put it at the end. Does change a thing.

I also tried the https://secure-apir instead of the non secure one, same problem.

I've written an email to the support and awaiting the answer.
Does anyone of you have spotted something I've missed?

Comment: The docs says the request should be in the format `/apir/1/route.{output}/{lg}[/{data}]?steps` and after seeing their example further down, your request should look like: `/apir/1/route.json/fra/?steps=....`. As you see, the `lg` is it's own slug, not a query parameter.

Comment: The example link at the bottom of the page has a slightly different "layout", have you tried using `/apir/1/route.json/fra/?steps=...` like in that example?

Comment: Oh god, i'm feeling so stupid right now, but thanks ^^